# Private Sub returning ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following function

```
    Public Function sorting(WS As Worksheets, Col As Range, Rng As Range, Sort_Order As XlSortOrder)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With WS

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Col, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=Sort_Order, DataOption:=xlSortNormal


        With .Sort


            .SetRange Rng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply


        End With


    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Function
```

Now I am trying to run the follow code based on the function.

```
Private Sub cmbCareerPath_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Set WS = Worksheets("FindPath")
    Set Col = WS.Range("D:D")
    Set Rng = WS.Range("A:Z")

        Call sorting(WS, Col, Rng, xlAscending)

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

However, when I run my Sub I get the compile error:

```
ByRef argument type mismatch
```

On the line below on WS.

Call sorting(**WS**, Column, Rng, xlAscending)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `WS` is a worksheet object. You are passing it to a WorkSheets collection. In your sub, change `WS as WorkSheets` to `WS as WorkSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare all your variables in subcarrerpathchange. Otherwise, you're passing variants. That will solve your immediate problem.
(as noted above, Dim as Worksheet, though right now it's seeing Variant, not Worksheets)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim col As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xla As XlSortOrder
```

Then Change your public function to ws as worksheet (not worksheets)